# How to order promql query's labels

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I've a Prometheus query `asterisk_endpoints_state` returning multiples vectors, here's an example of the labels, plus the current status value, either 0 or 1

```
asterisk_endpoints_state{eid="xx:yy:zz:00:11", environment="development", id="PJSIP/xxxxxx", instance="172.20.0.217:5039", job="consul_discovery", monitoring_server="localhost", owner="owner", resource="xxxxxx", service="asterisk_00", tech="PJSIP"}
```

I want to display all of those vectors in Grafana as a table with part of the information, and the row colored green or red. It's almost done : I've a Prometheus datasource, and a panel in a dashbaord querying `asterisk_endpoints_state` with a `Table` visualization, Table transform `Table`. Plus a bunch of column styles to remove some useless columns, one to colorize the row green or red depending on the value.

The last cosmetic detail which gives me trouble is, the table columns are ordered "automatically", no choice in the matter the tool tips says "Depends on the query result".

So my question is, how can I fiddle with the labels order in the promql query result itself ? So for example `resource` would come first ? If this is possible. Or if you got another way of doing that via Grafana, I'm all ears.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to reorder the columns.